# Capybara string-array type fill_in fails with factory-created data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara, factory-bot

I have a people table where a person has an array of emails.
In my schema.rb it looks like this:

```
create_table "people", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "email",                   array: true
```

My person-model validates presence of email: `validates :email, presence: true`

My people-controller creates person like this:

```
def create
  @person = Person.new(person_params)
  @person.email << person_params["email"] #Rails 4 strong parameters
  respond_to do |format|
    if @person.save!
      format.html { redirect_to people_url, notice: t('app.people.successful_save') }
      format.json { render :index, status: :created }
    else
      format.html { render :index}
      format.json { render json: @person.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

My form.html.haml asking email input:

```
= f.label  :person, t('app.people.email')
= f.text_field :email
```

Factory-piece that creates email (amongst other things):

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :person do
    # other stuff here...
    email ["mail1@example.com"]
    # ...and other stuff here
  end
end
```

And here is my feature-spec that fails:

```
it 'is able to create a new person' do
  person = build(:person)

  visit 'people'
  click_button 'New Person'

  within ("#new_person_form")do
    # other passing stuff here...
    fill_in 'person_email', :with => person.email # <----FAILURE HERE
    # ...and other not passing stuff here
  end
  click_button 'Save'
  expect(page).to have_content 'Person saved'
end
```

Error message itself:

```
Failure/Error: fill_in 'person_email', :with => person.email
 ArgumentError:
   Value cannot be an Array when 'multiple' attribute is not present. Not a Array
```

If I googled this message, I found this:
https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/selenium/node.rb#L30
Unfortunately I don't understand it very well. I also checked capybara cheat sheet for possible mistakes I might have been made but no good.

I get the spec to pass if I replace person.email with sth arbitrary like this:
    `fill_in 'person_email', :with => "sth.sth@mail.com"`

I have tried different kind of values for email in factory including with and without the array brackets- same error message appears.

I get different message when I create a person object instead of building it and using plain string in my email-field inside factory instead of an array- then my model fails email presence validation. But I guess it's logical because regarding to schema, model assumes getting array not string.

I'm not very experienced in RSpec yet so maybe it's a simple mistake.. Anyway help needed, thanks!

**UPDATE1:**
Person class definition:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, presence: true
end
```

Comment: What is the class definition for Person? Based on the error, the `email` method is returning an Array instead of a String.

Comment: Updated my question (validation is the only thing in Person class regarding to email). @andrey's answer did the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fill_in 'person_email', :with => person.email
```

That row is actually equivalent to the following one:

```
find(:fillable_field, 'person_email').set(person.email)
```

`person.email` returns an instance of Array but `person_email` field doesn't have attribute `multiple`. Such usage doesn't make any sense so Capybara raises error (How can you write several values to a single text field?).

Probably you want to do the following:

```
fill_in 'person_email', with: person.email.first
```

Comment: That solved the problem. Got confused because string value from factory was failing while replacing person.email call in spec with a plain string did help- thanks a lot!